# html video remove black bars

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I am embedding a html5 video but I have a black bar on top and bottom.

[image]

Now I have tried to put it inside a div and put a negative margin.

But then it goes over the gray padding above it. Now I can give the gray padding a higher z-index but when I scroll I still want the video to go over the gray padding.

Is there another way to remove the black bars or maybe change the color of the black bars?

Comment: if the bars are not from the video file, you just have to set `#your_video{background-color: yourColor;}` in CSS but the default is transparent in non-fullscreen mode.

Comment: Please add code simulation, so it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with below css

```
[data-next-video]{
height:unset !important
}
```

I use next-video library

Answer (score -1):

Add background color in the video tag